Spring Cloud Dataflow Server - NoSQL / MongoDB Database support
The latest milestone release for Spring batch (5.2.0-M2) has added support for MongoDB. Spring cloud dataflow server still requires an RDMBS (MySQL, PostgreSQL etc). Is there a feature request already in place for Spring cloud dataflow server to work with MongoDB or any other NoSQL databases?

Thank you for your question!
At this time SCDF nor Spring Cloud Task have support for NoSQL databases.   However I have created issues to add these features.   They can be found here and here.

Thank you for adding those issues to the backlog!
